# Splunk query to fetch http methods

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

Here is my log message. I am trying to capture all the http methods that are coming to /selfservice url.  Basically i want to find number of hits for each api with count for each GET, PUT, POST etc.

```
65791 > GET http://self-qa-auto-1.stage.xyz.com/selfservice
```

There could be other urls similar(like below) but i want to capture selfservice only

```
23721 > POST http://self-qa-auto-1.stage.xyz.com/payservice
```

Here is the thing i tried

```
| rex field=message "\s+(?<httpmethod>\s+)http.*xyz.com\/selfservice"
```

tried different possibilities but did not get the correct data.
any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i figured out and able to see the result

```
| rex field=message ">\s+(?<httpmethod>\w*).*/selfservice"
```